# Update line in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, line

I have an HTML table and at the end of each line there are two 2 buttons to change or add a  new line to the table.

I understand how to add a line in a table using jquery but now I want to change the data in a line of table if the change button is pressed.

Please let me know how to change the contents of a table line. I think a dialog-window should appear and allow the user to input some value, then click enter and see the updated line.

This is table code:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table-visual-features">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>Numeric</td>
            <td>Values to be mapped to the x-axis</td>
            <td>
                <button class="action_change">change</button>
                <button class="action-add-visual-feature">add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is code for the add action:

```
$('.action-add-visual-feature').on('click', function () {
    $('#table-visual-features tbody').append('<tr><td>x</td><td>Numeric</td><td>Values to be mapped to the x-axis</td><td><button class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger action-remove-visual-feature"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></button></td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and use the "numeric" and "xAxis" value to populate your dialog box for editing.

```
$('.action_change').on('click', function() {
    var numeric;
    var xAxis;
    $(this).closest('tr').each(function(){
    numeric = $(this).val();
    xAxis = $(this).val();
    });
    });
```

Also refer to [this link](http://www.safnet.com/writing/tech/2012/07/manipulating-table-rows-with-jquery.html#)

Comment: thak u. It is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Before or after appending, you can modify the contents using `.html()` and `.text()`.

```
// Creating cells and setting content
var cell1 = $('<td />').text('Column #1');
var cell2 = $('<td />').text('Column #2');
var cell3 = $('<td />').text('Column #3');

// Creating a row and appending cells
var row = $('<tr />');
row.append(cell1).append(cell2).append(cell3);

// appending the row
$('table').append(row);

// Modifying text of cell1 after appending
cell1.text('Live editing, whoop!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeevi/dTPpQ/) simple inline edit option. The same can be easily extended to show a dialog box.

```
$('.action_change').live('click', function(){
    $($(this).closest('tr').children('td')[1]).html('<input id="row-value-edit" type="text" /><button class="row-value-ok">OK</button>');
});

$('.row-value-ok').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('td').text($('#row-value-edit').val());
});
```

This code allows user to inline edit the table data. The new data entered in the textbox is reassigned to the table column.

Comment: thank you. but I see, that old value in cell is deleted, if I use your example. How can I solve it?

Comment: thank you. But .live does not work in my project.  How to write other?

Comment: .live() is deprecated since jquery 1.7 sorry to have suggested it to you. It has been replaced by .on() in version 1.9. Just use .on() in its place

Comment: this line does not work with .live and .on


$('.row-value-ok').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('td').text($('#row-value-edit').val());
    
});

Comment: Hi. Can u see my code.  http://jsfiddle.net/jaW7m/ I do not understand, why I must click 2 times on button?  In different case I show strange value